# How to highlight any amount of (possibly duplicated) As, followed by non-greedy matcher, then by any amount of Bs etc. (without unreasonable limits)?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, highlight

The example below is a demo of the type of highlighting that I want (for `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` and `"d"`):

```js
var reg = new RegExp("(.*?)([a]{1,})(.*?)([b]{1,})(.*?)([c]{1,})(.*?)([d]{1,})(.*?)", "gi");
var txt = "OK, abacd, abcdt, yaaaxxbyycccczzddddg0011".replace(reg,
  '$1<mark>$2</mark>$3<mark>$4</mark>$5<mark>$6</mark>$7<mark>$8</mark>$9');
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
```

The problem here is, obviously, a limit of `n=9` in `$n`. But what if I want to do this for more than four chars (that is, without **unreasonable** limits)? How to solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't [`txt.replace(/[a-d]+/gi, '<mark>$&</mark>');`](https://jsfiddle.net/7kmyqdrw/) suffice?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: `abcd` shouldn't be highlighted.

Comment: @georg: That is secondary, the idea is to not use any groups. Here is another - but using the same idea - [approach with `txt.replace(/([a-d])\1*/gi, '<mark>$&</mark>');`](https://jsfiddle.net/7kmyqdrw/1/)

Comment: Is the order important? How should this be highlighted: `bbbb XXX aaa XXX ccc`?

Comment: @georg: Is the order important? // Yes, see the edited question.

Comment: Ok, that is now clearer. I do not see a problem with expanding the regex "manually". If you need to match a sequence of subpatterns, you need to define them in your pattern. Surely, you might want to build such a pattern dynamically though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt using [function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) in `replace()`

This is more like dynamic pattern mentioned by [@WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)

```js
var reg = new RegExp(["a", "b", "c", "d"].map(a => "([" + a + "]{1,})(.*?)").reduce((a, i) => a + i, "(.*?)"), "gi");
var txt1 = "OK, abacd, abcdt, yaaaxxbyycccczzddddg0011"
  .replace(reg, (m, ...p) => {
    p.pop();//pop string
    p.pop();//pop offset
    return p.reduce((a, i, ix) => a + (ix % 2 ? "<mark>" + i + '</mark>' : i), '')
  });

var txt = "OK, abacd, abcdt, yaaaxxbyycccczzddddg0011"
  .replace(reg, (m, ...p) => {
    p.pop();
    p.pop();
    return "<br><br>-match-" + m + p.reduce((a, i, ix) => a + "<br>-substring-" + (ix % 2 ? i : "-h-" + i), '')
  });
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt1 + txt;
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex won't give you the entire solution, it can only be one part of the solution. Use regex to isolate the individual matches, then iterate through these matches and do the replacements one by one. In this case the iterations are done by passing a function-definition to `.replace()` and that function itself has another `for`-loop to do the actual replacements.

I've also simplified the regex, `[a]` is simply `a` and `{1,}` is equivalent with just `+`. Then if you just place the chars you wanna match in an array you can `.join()` them together to make the regex, as well this array is used inside the function to work from the last `<mark>...</mark>` *backwards* to the first. Going backwards helps to both ensure that the found `a` is still at the front of the entire match until the last insertion of `<mark>...</mark>`. It also prevents from getting stuff like `<mar<mark>k</mark>>` (the reason I added `'k'` to the array was to test this).

You can see no regex ever goes higher than `$2` even though the code highlights 5 characters from the `chars` array. You can make this array arbitrarily long to fit you needs. I've also added a `<textarea>` so you can see the regexes that are being generated inside the `for`-loop.

```js
var chars = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k'];
var fillr = '+[^<]*?';
var txt = "OK, abacdk, abcdtk, yaaaxxbyycccczzddddgkkkk0011"
  .replace(new RegExp(chars.join(fillr) + '+', 'gi'),
    function(m) {
      for (var i = chars.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var rgx = '^' +
          ((i!=0)?
            ('(' + chars.slice(0, i).join(fillr) + fillr + ')'):
            '()'
          ) +
          '('+chars[i]+'+)';
        document.getElementById('srccode').value += i + '\t' + m + '\n\t' + rgx + '\n';
        m = m.replace(new RegExp(rgx, 'gi'), '$1<mark>$2</mark>');
        document.getElementById('srccode').value += '\t' + m + '\n\n';
      }
      return m.replace(/<\/mark>(\s*)<mark>/gi, '$1');
    }
  );
document.getElementById('srccode').value += '\n'+txt;
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<body>
  <textarea id="srccode" rows="10" style="width:100%;white-space: nowrap; overflow:scroll;"></textarea>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this solution is faster and works in older browsers, compared to sabithpocker's answer.

Comment: It also prevents from getting stuff like `<mar<mark>k</mark>>` // Try your current answer for `['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k']` with `"OK, aabaaccddxkkk0"`. I see `OK, aaark>baaccddxkkk0`. I thought that stuff like this should be prevented automatically! But you can edit the code, if it's possible...

Comment: Ah, nice find! Didn't realize this could be a use-case. I updated the answer to handle this correctly.